# O PHP não retorna o segundo parâmetro via URL no Google Chrome

Tags: php, get

Parece uma coisa boba, mas é verdade.

A url: http://musicasitalianas.com/vedere/vede_musica.php?a=us&b=r

o código PHP desse arquivo

```
echo $_GET["a"];
echo $_GET["b"];
```

O resultado: `us`

O que tem de errado?

> Isto acontece apenas no navegador **Google Chrome**. Em outros, o resultado é o esperado.

Comment: Parece correto ... da um `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: Aqui apareceu `usr` como esperado. Já tentou limpar o cache do navegador? Talvez seja uma versão anterior que esteja exibindo.

Comment: vou limpar agora

Comment: nada, na verdade criei esse arquivo agora para teste porque estou enfrentando o mesmo problema em um arquivo que se utiliza de $_GET. Vou tentar com outro navegador

Comment: sim em outro navegador funciona a contento. Problema é no Crhome. Devo mudar a pergunta então certo?

Comment: Sim, acredito que este detalhe seja relevante, mas continua sendo estranho que apenas aí não funciona. Provavelmente seja alguma configuração do navegador.

Comment: Aqui está funcionando no chrome tmb

Comment: pois é, desde ontem trabalhando nisso e nada. Ideia, vou testar em outro PC.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta pegar os parâmetros dessa forma, pois aqui testei e funcionou normal tanto por `$_GET` quanto por `parse_url`

```
<?php
    $url = "http://m...content-available-to-author-only...s.com/vedere/vede_musica.php?a=us&b=r";
    $result = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($result['query'], $var);

    print_r($var);
?>
```

Isso vai retornar:

```
Array
(
    [a] => us
    [b] => r
)
```

`$var` agora é um `array` com os parâmetros passados na URL.

[Exemplo Idone](http://ideone.com/9us8v9)

Comment: inclui seu código no arquivo e por incrível que pareça agora vem tudo que tem direito

Comment: tenho uma pagina que tem if (echo $_GET["cantor"]){ .....  Mais pra frente  if ($_GET["musica"]){ ..... esse ultimo não funciona de jeito nenhum. Vou ver com seu código

Comment: Você está usando o if para verificar qual o GET na url, da forma que você descreveu?

Comment: não, assim  if (isset($_GET['musica'])) { ...

Comment: Se estiver usando esse isset, na página cuja url você colocou na pergunta, ele não vai funcionar mesmo, mas isso é bem provável que seja algo no seu navegador. Pois testei aqui e funcionou sem problemas

Comment: Não xara, uso esse isset em outras partes do código, alias, vários isset, e todos funcionam bem. Acabei de retirar a sua parte do código e agora o meu anterior funciona.

Comment: Reavalie seu código linha por linha então, provavelmente algum erro de digitação estava invalidando o código

Comment: A pergunta enão é, migrei para a tecnologia Cloud, será que há retardo nas atualizações dos arquivos via FTP ?

Comment: Não sei lhe dizer ao certo sobre isso, mas se esse é o caso provavelmente você está fazendo atualizações nos seus arquivos mas o seu Cloud ainda está usando a versão em cachê dos seus arquivos, eu usava Cloud anteriormente, e parei por esse motivo.

Comment: valeu, vou ver isso com o suporte do servidor

Comment: dito pelo suporte: cloud we have server which will cache your website which will fetch the contents. As you have cache the update will take some time

Comment: Parei de usar Cloud's por esse motivo, eu precisava fazer atualizações constantes no código e o cache demorava pra atualizar

Comment: só que funciona bem nos outros 3 sites, só em um que não, e esse um é o principal que está na raiz, os outros estão dentro das respectivas pastas embora tenham domínios proprios.

Comment: agora está tudo normal, acho que era problema na migração para o cloud, levou mais de 24 horas, Uffa, ainda bem que voltou ao normal. Então fiquem espertos, migrar para as nuvens NÃO FAÇAM ATUALIZAÇÔES ANTES DE 48 horas. Periodo de propagação é 24 horas, as outras 24 é por minha conta. rs